# Limitar o counter() a um certo nivel da lista de listas

Tags: css

Tenho este HTML que não posso mudar:

```
<ol>
    <li>Main
        <ul>
            <li>Secondary A</li>
            <li>Secondary B</li>
            <li>Secondary C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

E estou a numerar esta lista via CSS com:

```
ol li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
```

O resultado é basicamente este:

```
1. Main
    2. Secondary A
    3. Secondary B
    4. Secondary C
```

Mas o que eu pretendo só ter o contador no primeiro nivel desta lista de listas. No fundo que ficasse assim:

```
1. Main
    Secondary A
    Secondary B
    Secondary C
```

Não mudando o HTML qual a melhor maneira maneira de impedir a contagem de continuar nas listas internas?

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trmcxasz/**

Testando o problema mais extensivamente reparo que omitir `content: counter(li);` [funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/trmcxasz/5/), o que à partida não me faz muito sentido pois estou a omitir o "content"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para limitares a propagação do estilo que pretendes aplicar, podes fazer uso do seletor [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships) que te limita o mesmo ao filho direto sem propagar para "netos" e "bisnetos", etc.

**Teu código alterado:**

```
ol > li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
}
```

Assim, apenas as `li` diretamente abaixo da `ol` é que são afetadas.